# Distro agnostic markdown to rtf/html converter

Tags: linux, markdown

Is there a tool that comes preinstalled in most Linux distros that would let me convert a markdown file to an HTML or an rtf file?

Answer (score 3):

[PanDoc](https://pandoc.org/getting-started.html#step-1-install-pandoc)

Not pre-installed but it is available in most of the major distribution repositories and works on command line

Comment: +1 for this and there is nothing even remotely like it which comes standard on any Linux distro out of the box AFAIK.